# PBS torque email variable

Tags: cluster-computing, pbs, torque

Here is an example of pbs that I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -N myJob
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=4
#PBS -l walltime=50:00:00
#PBS -q route

export MYMAIL=mytestmail@testmail.com
#PBS -m ae
#PBS -M mytestmail@testmail.com

./script1.sh

echo $PBS_JOBID $PBS_O_WORKDIR | mail -s "$PBS_JOBNAME script1 done" $MYMAIL

./script2.sh

echo $PBS_JOBID $PBS_O_WORKDIR | mail -s "$PBS_JOBNAME script2 done" $MYMAIL

./script3.sh

echo $PBS_JOBID $PBS_O_WORKDIR | mail -s "$PBS_JOBNAME script3 done" $MYMAIL

./script4.sh
```

As you can see I want to receive notifications during the process.
My problem is that users must write twice their email address.

I tried:

```
#PBS -M  $MYMAIL
```

but it does not work.

I also tried to find a pbs variable containing the email stored during

```
#PBS -M mytestmail@testmail.com
```

but nothing ...

An idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are sending different emails by different methods. With the #PBS -M line you are telling pbs_server on the head node where is should send emails about the job and with "|mail " you are sending mail to the user from the node running the job.

It seems that Torque does not set an environment variable that contains the contents of -M so we can't pass that to mail.

I have two ideas for you. The first is trying to capture the Mail_Users line from qstat and parsing it.

```
qstat -f [job number] | grep Mail_Users
```

The second is to create a .forward file for each user since Torque will email the local user account by default eliminating the #PBS -M line. You will still need to pass an email or account name to mail but you may be able to get away with:

```
mail -s "$PBS_JOBNAME script1 done" `whoami`
```

Comment: Thanks ! `qstat -f [job number] | grep Mail_Users` works fine.